# Generic URL rewrite keeping query string

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

What is the proper Apache mod_rewrite rule to change any

```
mydomain.com/?var1=val1&var2=val2&...&mode=app_mode&varN=valN&...
```

type query to

```
mydomain.com/app_mode/?var1=val1&var2=val2&...&varN=valN&...
```

(If the `mode` variable is not present in the `QUERY_STRING`, the URL should be kept as is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?mode=([^&]+)(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%2/?%1%3 [L,R=302,NE]
```

This allows `mode` parameter to be anywhere in the query string.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right. The point is, that `app_mode` comes from the `QUERY_STRING`'s `mode` parameter, so it has to be extracted as a path, and the rest of the `QUERY_STRING` kept as is.